# Entity Framework Powertools - Code First Generate Views On Build

Tags: entity-framework

Right now Power Tools Beta 4 provides generation of views with a right click. This is fine as far as it goes but can cause issues because you have to remember to do it.

Is there any way that I can make it do the generation of views at compile time? (i.e. some sort of pre-build action or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use T4 templates for generating views I created a while ago. Take a look [here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/10/02/entity-framework-code-first-view-generation-templates-updated/) for the EF5 version and [here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/10/17/ef6-codefirst-view-generation-t4-template-for-c-updated-for-ef6-rtm/) for the EF6 version. You will need to do some MSBuild work to make the T4 template run on Build. You can take a look at comments for [this blog post](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/10/08/t4-templates-for-generating-views-for-ef4ef5-databasemodel-first-apps/) where this is discussed a little bit.

**EDIT**
I also recently published [Interactive Views](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/12/14/using-pre-generated-views-without-having-to-pre-generate-views-ef6/) for EF6 on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFInteractiveViews) so now you can have pre-generated views without having to generate them at the build time.